# bytearray to string

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

One trick shown me that I could use `bytes+""` which convert into String but not a pure String. It is acceptable by any UI components except it won't accept when I throw `bytes+""` into `switch` statement. How do I convert bytearray to pure string?

```
private function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
    try {
        rsocket = event.target as Socket;
        bytes = new ByteArray();
        rsocket.readBytes(bytes);
        kEvent(bytes+"");
        rsocket.flush();
    } catch (error:Error) {
        Alert.show(error.message, "Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your string is UTF8, you can just do the following:

```
var myString:String = bytes.readUTF();
```

You can see this in the documentation here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html

Comment: I got "#2030: End of file was encountered" error after the conversion, what should I do?

Comment: In that case, the string isn't formatted according to the specifications that the Flash Player is expecting (there has to be an unsigned integer at the beginning of the array that indicates the number of bytes).  YOu can either specify the number of bytes and use the readUTFBytes method or you'll have to do the conversion manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just use *toString()* method.

```
var ba:ByteArray;
var str:String = ba.toString();
```

Comment: and how you convert it back? writeUTF?